# Visual Studio 2010 displays an error when I try to view a projects Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I get the following error when i try to open a projects properties page in Visual Studio 2010:

```
An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))
```

Anyone seen this before.  I found one suggestion of reinstalling .net 4 but this didn't seem to make any difference.  The problem seems to have happened after we joined our Team Foundation server to the domain, but I can't see how that would have caused the problem.

This is the same for any project.